# How can I skip the cart and go straight to checkout in the Shopify store?

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I need to add "**Buy now**" button on product collection page and with the help of this button product is directly added in to the cart.

Can any one help me with this??

Answer (score 2):

You can have a simpl**e “BUY NOW”** button for a product in Shopify that takes the customer directly to the checkout page. It will most likely increase your conversion rate because it removes a step (the cart page) from the purchasing process. Your customers will leap to the checkout page, ready to pay!

**In product-template.liquid find the following code:**

```
<span id="AddToCartText-{{ section.id }}">
```

Make a backup of your file and right underneath it enter this code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="return_to" value="/checkout/" />
```

Customers will still be able to get back to cart from the breadcrumbs on the Checkout page and icon on your website, but it's a start.

Comment: This does not work anymore, is there any new method?

Comment: Not quite the same, but the new official approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72070166/how-to-skip-cart-page-and-redirect-to-checkout-in-the-new-shopify-dawn https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/online-store/dynamic-checkout/add-buttons#add-or-remove-dynamic-checkout-buttons-on-product-pages