# How to skip cart page and redirect to checkout in the new Shopify Dawn

Tags: jquery, shopify, liquid

I've searched and tried countless things to check how I can redirect to checkout directly when clicking add to cart on a product page.

It was really easy to do before with an input with a specific "return_to" parameter.

Now there is 0 info on this.

How would I do this ? Default (Dawn) theme.

Thank you?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a newer theme you should be able to do it from your Shopify settings:

1. From your Shopify admin, go to Online Store > Themes.
2. Find the theme that you want to edit, and then click Customize.
3. Open the drop-down menu at the top of the page.
4. Select Product pages.
5. Click the Product pages section.
6. Check or uncheck Show dynamic checkout button.
7. Click Save.

[click here for more info](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/online-store/dynamic-checkout/add-buttons#add-or-remove-dynamic-checkout-buttons-on-product-pages)